# How to configure auditd to collect logs from /proc

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, logs, proc, linux-audit

I've been looking for this for about 2 days and have come up empty-handed.
I am looking for a way to build a threat alert for Linux-based credential dumping in Splunk.

To do this, I need to be able to monitor the `/proc` directory. I found audit and auditd (audit daemon) but I don't know how to actually configure auditd to monitor `/proc`. If I could do this I could then connect `audit.log` to Splunk.

I want to at least monitor:

- `/proc/<PID>/maps`
- `/proc/<PID>/mem`
- `/proc/<PID>/cmdline`

But ideally I want to monitor everything in `/proc`.

Has anyone here ever done this? If so, I would really appreciate some help.

Additionally, I found klogd (kernel log deamon), but I don't know how to configure that to `/proc` either or if that is even what I need.

I am of course open to other methods and ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Using RHEL and SplunkForwarder in my environment. The `auditd` is configured according [Defining Audit Rules](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-defining_audit_rules_and_controls) or [Introducing an Audit Rule Set](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book.security/cha.audit.scenarios.html).

To define a file system watch (`-w`) rule

```
auditctl -w <filePath> -p permissions -k <keyName>
```

with permissions that are logged

- r - reading file or directory
- w - writing to file or directory
- x - execute
- a - attribute change

i.e. `-p wa`.

Monitoring everything in `/proc` might to much.